# Capturing variable returned by API in Flask

Tags: python, api, oop, flask

I'm trying to capture a variable generated by Flask after visiting a certain URL.
I want to use that variable in further authorization in the API.

Due to the nature of Flask, every time the user visits the web app's URL, a function is called that returns a variable.

I want to capture that variable and use it further, without executing the function (the function should be executed only once).

Here's the code I have:

```
@app.route("/callback/")
def callback_code():
    auth_code = request.args.get('code')
    return auth_code

code = callback_code()

tracks_endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks"
tracks_auth = {
    "Authorization":f"Bearer {code}"
}

tracks = requests.get(tracks_endpoint, headers=tracks_auth)
```

The problem is caused by:

```
code = callback_code()
```

After visiting http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth, Flask displays the following error:

*RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.*

How can I capture **auth_code** and store it, without executing the function?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Because you have no `app`. I don't see how you want this cyclical code to work. Your route expects a request containing `auth_code` and you want to send a request to that route to get an `auth_code`. Wut?

Comment: We can't see `auth` but `code = callback_code()` is going to run before you actually send the request (scripts run top-to-bottom) so I think this is probably broken in several other ways, not just the immediate problem

Comment: "Due to the nature of Flask"? Not quite... The logic of returning anything is up to how you wrote the function

Answer (score 0):

So first problem is that you're expecting the server to be running and get some callback, but the code that is not intended in a function is going to be immeadiately ran, externally from the Flask server lifecycle.

Best way I can think to handle that would be to have your callback redirect to another endpoint, and save off your auth token somewhere in between (such as a session cookie)

Or using a separate variable, for example

```
AUTH = { 
  'spotify': None
}

tracks_endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks"

@app.route("/callback/")
def callback_code():
    auth_code = request.args.get('code')
    AUTH['spotify'] = auth_code
    return redirect(url_for('tracks'))

@app.route("/tracks")
def tracks():
    if not AUTH['spotify']:
        raise('Auth code not loaded. Login first')
    tracks_auth = {
      "Authorization":f"Bearer AUTH['spotify']"
    }
    tracks = requests.get(tracks_endpoint, headers=tracks_auth)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is extremely useful and what I was aiming for, but the value for 'Spotify' in AUTH dictionary still remains empty, so in the 'tracks_auth' dict, the value renders to "Bearer None". That is the part I'm trying to crack - how to store a value received in a callback in an external variable to use it later on.

Comment: Are you sure `request.args.get('code')` is correct?